# Using javascript to select text and the containing element using createRange

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I'm rolling my own generic wysiwyg editor but Im stuck selecting some text. I'm using a div with contenteditable set to true to enter the text into. The problem is I'm using a `<var>` tag to highlight some text that the user is supposed to delete and rewrite in their own words. When the text inside the `<var>` tag is clicked it highlights it as I expect but when you hit backspace it only deletes the text and not the tags (`<var>`). How can I tell the selection to grab a few more characters on each end of the selection so it also deletes the `<var>` tags? I'm using the following to make the selection happen.

```
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(elem);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placed function on the `div`'s `click` event.

Selected the `<var>` tag.

Used `.selectNode` rather than `.selectNodeContents`.

Browsers handle it differently though. Some will add `<i></i>` tags when you enter more text, others don't, but this does remove the `<var>` tag completely....

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var elem = document.getElementById("myVar");
myDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(elem);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);            
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="myDiv">
Hello, this<var id="myVar"> is a test</var> of the editor
</div>
```